# WordPress loop by meta key that is an array? and how loop multiple arrays

Tags: php, custom-field, loop, post-meta, array

How can I get loop of posts by meta values that save in a meta_key that is an array like that

```
$sharedHosting_plans_fields = Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => Array
                                            (
                                                [plan_name] => name 1
                                                [plan_price] => 1
                                                [theType] => yesPaid
                                                [plan_space] => Unlimited
                                            )

                                        [1] => Array
                                            (
                                                [plan_name] => name 2
                                                [plan_price] => 3
                                                [theType] => yesFree
                                                [plan_space] => 5000
                                            )

                                        [2] => Array
                                            (
                                                [plan_name] => name2
                                                [plan_price] => 5
                                                [theType] => yesPaid
                                                [plan_space] => Unlimited
                                            )

                                    )
```

And I have used this

```
     'meta_key' => 'sharedHosting_plans_fields',
     'orderby' => 'meta_value_num meta_value ',
```

but no effect!!!

2-If i want to get posts by checking multiple meta keys like that

```
    array(
         'key' => 'plan_type2'
    ),
    array(
         'key' => 'plan_type3'
    ),
    array(
         'key' => 'plan_type4'
    ),
    array(
         'key' => 'plan_type5'
    ),
```

How I can short hand this code by for loop or any thing else?

I have tried to use

```
    'meta_key' => array('sharedHosting_plans_fields'),
     'orderby' => 'meta_value_num meta_value ',
```

instead of

```
    'meta_key' => 'sharedHosting_plans_fields',
     'orderby' => 'meta_value_num meta_value ',
```

but no luck

Answer (score 1):

You can't order by values inside serialised arrays in post meta. When you store an array like this:

```
$value = [
    [
            'plan_name'  => 'name 1',
            'plan_price' => '1',
            'theType'    => 'yesPaid',
            'plan_space' => 'Unlimited',
    ],
    [
            'plan_name'  => 'name 2',
            'plan_price' => '3',
            'theType'    => 'yesFree',
            'plan_space' => '5000',
    ],
    [
            'plan_name'  => 'name2',
            'plan_price' => '5',
            'theType'    => 'yesPaid',
            'plan_space' => 'Unlimited',
    ],
]
```

This is stored in PHP like this:

```
a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:9:"plan_name";s:6:"name 1";s:10:"plan_price";s:1:"1";s:7:"theType";s:7:"yesPaid";s:10:"plan_space";s:9:"Unlimited";}i:1;a:4:{s:9:"plan_name";s:6:"name 2";s:10:"plan_price";s:1:"3";s:7:"theType";s:7:"yesFree";s:10:"plan_space";s:4:"5000";}i:2;a:4:{s:9:"plan_name";s:5:"name2";s:10:"plan_price";s:1:"5";s:7:"theType";s:7:"yesPaid";s:10:"plan_space";s:9:"Unlimited";}}
```

As far as MySQL — which is responsible for querying posts — is concerned, this is just a long string. Indistinguihsable from a word or sentence that begins with `a`. It's only turned back into an array by WordPress when the value is retrieved with `get_post_meta()`.

So it's not possible to sort by a property within an array, and if you attempt to sort by the meta value of this meta then it's just going to sort as if this were a string.

If you need to sort this way then you need to find an alternate way of storing the data. I don't have enough insight into your project to suggest anything specific, but you probably need a custom database table for these plans, which you'd then need to join and sort using the `posts_join` and `posts_orderby` hooks to modify the query SQL directly.

Comment: Thanks but I want to get posts that have this meta value "yesPaid" and you have told me that's will happen if I sort this value in a separated field only so I ask How can I search inside this array meta key?

2-It's an array because it have many values from repeated custom fields

3-Could you answer my question number two?

Comment: I answered your question, at length: You can’t.